# Command to reread partitions from media

Tags: partition, block-device, media

When I insert media (e.g. an SD card) the system (Ubuntu 12.04) reads the partition table and creates all the /dev/*[1234] links to each partition. If I repartition the media I have to physically remove and reinsert it to update these links. Is there a command to force this to happen without me having to remove and reinsert the disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `partprobe` command. Run it without arguments to re-read the partition table on all disks, or with a specific device to only re-read for that device, e.g. `partprobe /dev/sda`.